# How to check if a string contians "st", "nd", "rd", "th"?

Tags: c#

I am wondering if there is a way to check a string for a number and the their suffix (st, nd, rd, th):

```
12th = true
3rd = true
Smith = false
11th ST = true
5 = false
21st = true
```

I know I can do this

```
bool st = address.Contains("1ST");
bool nd = address.Contains("2ND");
bool rd = address.Contains("3RD");
bool th = address.Contains("4TH");
...
```

Which can work but this doesn't seem like the most efficient way and I'm hoping there is a better way.

Comment: How about using an Array/List to contain your strings and do a for loop?

Comment: you also need to account for string like "sah3RD" which will return true even for invalid number. Why do you need to check a string like this?

Comment: The title is a bit misleading. You're not checking if a string contains those substrings, your looking for the combination of the number and the string. And "efficient"/"better" requires an objective definition of "efficient" or "better". For example, fewer lines of code, less processor cycles, less memory, etc.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was wanting something like what Joel provided. Short and works. No need to be spending time typing same line over and over when you can do it in 1 line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is probably the way to go here. This expression can do it:

```
\d+\s?(?i)(st|nd|rd|th)
```

See it here:

> https://regex101.com/r/Zmx0F4/1

The C# would look like this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(address, @"\d+\s?(?i)(st|nd|rd|th)");
```

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/EjhDpI

Comment: Why `\s?`? I think there shouldn't be any space between.

Comment: @PoulBak You might be right. I was thinking I've seen ordinals expressed with a space before, but now that I think again it seems like it would be odd. Maybe I was thinking units. Easy to remove that part, though.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for you quick answer.  For those wondering the code line ended up looking like this Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\d+\s?(?i)(st|nd|rd|th)");

Comment: Probably, the pattern `\b(\d*1st|\d*2nd|\d*3rd|\d*[0,4-9]th|\d*1\dth)\b` would be more correct.